# reactjs - json and nested loops in template

Tags: json, reactjs

I am new to reactjs, I've json which has some nested arrays and need to replicate the static markup with conditionals as I loop though the json.

I've seen some methods that use .reduce and push the data into nested arrays after a particular modulus has been reached.

how do I add the required wrappers to match/mirror the static markup?

//this is what I have so far

```
    {
      lang.contact[0].groups.map(function (item, index) {
        return (
          <div className='row grid__row--offset--30' key={index}>
            <div className='medium-8 small-15 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
              <img className='icn__large centered' src={item.image} alt='illustrated skyscraper' />
            </div>
            {
              item.children.map(function (list, j) {
                return (
                  <div key={j} className='medium-22 small-60 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
                    <h3 className='text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10'>{list.title}</h3>
                    {
                      list.listings.map(function (sublist, k) {
                        return (
                          <p key={k} className='text--white text--center--small'>{sublist}</p>
                        )
                      })
                    }
                  </div>
                )
              })
            }
            <div className='small-15 small-centered columns show-for-small-only'>
              <div className='relative-container-40' />
              <div className='hor-line--thin--red' />
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      })
    }
```

//json

```
"contact"         : [
                    {
                        "title"   : "Impressum",
                        "groups"   : [
                            {
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "Firma",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "e-profound GmbH"                   
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image"       : "/img/home/imprint_icn_06.png"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "Email",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "info@e-profound.com"                   
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image"       : "/img/home/imprint_icn_01.png"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "Adresse",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "Grillparzerstrasse 37a",
                                            "81675 München",
                                            "Deutschland"                       
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image"       : "/img/home/imprint_icn_02.png"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "Handelsregister",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "HRB 209728"    
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "Umsatzsteuer-Ident-Nummer",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "DE293534729"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image"       : "/img/home/imprint_icn_05.png"
                            },
                            {
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "Management",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "Isidora Dekalo-Baron",
                                            "Alexander Baron"   
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "Responsible for the content",
                                        "listings": [
                                            "Isidora Dekalo-Baron",
                                            "Alexander Baron"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "image"       : "/img/home/imprint_icn_03.png"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

//original markup

```
<div class="small-56 columns small-centered">

                <!-- first row  -->
                <!-- ********************************************************* -->

                <div class="row grid__row--offset--30 ">
                    <div class="medium-8 small-15 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <img class="icn__large centered" src="/img/home/imprint_icn_06.png" alt="illustrated skyscraper">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-22 small-60 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">Company name</h3>
                        <p class="text--white text--center--small">e-profound GmbH</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-15 small-centered columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                        <div class="hor-line--thin--red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider line small only -->

                    <div class="small-60 columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider row small only -->

                    <div class="medium-8 small-15 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <img class="icn__large centered" src="/img/home/imprint_icn_01.png" alt="illustrated paper plane with airmail markings">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-22 small-60 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">E-mail</h3>
                        <p class="text--white text--center--small">info@e-profound.com</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-15 small-centered columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                        <div class="hor-line--thin--red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider line small only -->

                </div><!--row end -->

                <!-- second row  -->
                <!-- ********************************************************* -->

                <div class="row grid__row--offset--30">

                    <div class="medium-8 small-15 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <img class="icn__large centered" src="/img/home/imprint_icn_02.png" alt="illustrated waypoint">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-22 small-60 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">Address</h3>
                        <address>
                            <p class="text--white text--center--small">Grillparzerstrasse 37a</p>
                            <p class="text--white text--center--small">81675 Munich</p>
                            <p class="text--white text--center--small">Germany</p>
                        </address>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-15 small-centered columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                        <div class="hor-line--thin--red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider line small only -->

                    <div class="small-60 columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider row small only -->

                    <div class="medium-8 small-15 small-centered medium-uncentered columns">
                        <img class="icn__large centered" src="/img/home/imprint_icn_05.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="medium-22 small-60 small-centered medium-uncentered  columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-60 columns">
                                <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">Commercial register</h3>
                                <p class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-top-5">HRB 209728</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row grid__row--offset--15">
                            <div class="small-60 columns">
                                <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">VAT ID number:</h3>
                                <p class="text--white text--center--small">DE293534729</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>



                </div>
                <!--row end-->

                <div class="small-15 small-centered columns show-for-small-only">
                    <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                    <div class="hor-line--thin--red"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- divider line small only -->

                <!-- third row  -->
                <!-- ********************************************************* -->

                <div class="row grid__row--offset--30">
                    <div class="medium-8 small-15 small-centered medium-uncentered  columns">
                        <img class="icn__large centered" src="/img/home/imprint_icn_03.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="medium-22 small-60 small-centered medium-uncentered  columns">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="small-60 columns">
                                <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">Management</h3>
                                <p class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-top-5">Isidora Dekalo-Baron</p>
                                <p class="text--white text--center--small">Alexander Baron</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row grid__row--offset--15">
                            <div class="small-60 columns">
                                <h3 class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-bottom-10">Responsible for the content</h3>
                                <p class="text--white text--center--small paragraph-margin-top-5">Isidora Dekalo-Baron</p>
                                <p class="text--white text--center--small">Alexander Baron</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="small-15 small-centered columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                        <div class="hor-line--thin--red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider line small only -->

                    <div class="small-60 columns show-for-small-only">
                        <div class="relative-container-40"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- divider row small only -->

                                    </div>
                <!-- row large & medium -->

            </div>
```

Comment: What's the actual question ?

Comment: Trying to loop through to add the wrappers

Comment: the questions  -- how do I add the required wrappers to match/mirror the static markup